# Should selenium auto-test wait to load all the elements of the page or just the needed item?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm a beginner in testing and I'm starting to create automated tests. I got a project in which, methods are waiting for the item to appear and then the action is done on it, there is no page factory applied. I wonder if this is a good approach. Should I use methods to check all the items o page I need to load and just start the action but it will increase the test? Can he do as he was and wait for each item separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me try to address your points one by one:

1. Currently methods are waiting for items to appear : Yes, we have to do that. Sometime we have to wait for certain elements to be visible after some particular action is performed. That's the reason Thread.sleep(), ImplicitlyWait(), Explicit Wait & FluentWait is commonly used.
2. Yes, you can create methods to check all the items on one page you want to load & that's called PageFactory which is based on Page Object Model commonly known as POM.
3. Having said that I would like to add, still in some cases though the elements are already defined but you may have to induce one of the above mentioned Waits for the elements to be visible/clickable to perform your next action.

Let me know if I have addressed your query.

Answer (score 0):

I generally pick a single element that I know will be one of the last to load. Sometimes this element is picked through trial and error. I wait for that element to load which guarantees that the page is loaded. At that point, you shouldn't have to wait for any new elements to load before performing actions unless one of the actions you trigger causes the page or a portion of the page to reload. In that case, trigger the action and then wait for the page/portion of the page to reload before exiting the method.

Answer (score -1):

Usually it's a best practice, if you can wait for all the elements on your page to load (i.e implicit wait) unless it takes too much time waiting for all the elements to appear (i.e explicit/fluentwait).

It totally depends on your requirement; if you can manage to run your script without waiting for all the elements and without breaking your script then its all well and good.